# Clean install macOS keeps restarting and returning to macOS Utilities

Tags: macbook-pro, install, ssd, mojave

I'm trying to do a clean install of macOS Mojave on my 2012 13" MacBook Pro using a bootable USB. I'm doing it on a new 1 TB SSD that I've installed after my last one died.

The problem I'm having is that ever time I run the installer, everything looks like it's working, but then towards the end of the installation, the computer restarts and ultimately returns to the macOS Utilities menu.

I've tried formatting the hard drive several times and have even tried installing OS X Mountain Lion via an Internet recovery.

I'm struggling to find a solution to this, so would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you elaborate on what happens when to attempt to install OS X Mountain Lion via Internet recovery? Does it work? How fast and reliable is your Internet connection?

Comment: Hi Nimesh :) When I tried to do Mountain Lion, it eventually restarted to a white screen with a flashing folder and question mark icon.  My internet connection is generally pretty fast and reliable.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your Mac is unable to locate the startup disk (https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204156). It's advisable to check the connection of your hard drive. Make sure that the hard drive is in perfectly working condition and your Mac is able to detect it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If the disk is showing up alright in Disk Utilities does that mean that it's being detected?

Comment: Yes. If it's shown with the right capacity in Disk Utilities, it's detected fine.

Comment: Cool. Well the drive shows up in Disk Utilities as the correct capacity.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you shut down your computer and boot after unplugging the thumb drive? Also, is this the retina version or the model with superdrive?

Comment: I'd try reconnecting the drive and re-attempt the installation. If that doesn't work, I'd try accessing the hard drive on a different computer, check a different hard drive on the Mac to check against defects.

Comment: If I boot without the thumb drive then (after a while) it goes to the flashing question mark in a folder.  This is not the retina version.  So just has a superdrive.

Comment: Tried reconnecting the drive and re-attempting installation (via thumbdrive) and it just returns back to the macOS Utilities menu again.  Also tried connecting the SSD to another computer (via a caddy) and it was recognised immediately as a APFS formatted drive containing OS X install files..... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone having this issue in the future. The problem was the hard drive cable.  I've replaced it and now everything is working properly.